# Ipad -webkit-box-flex is Super Slow

Tags: ipad, css, webkit

I have an weird issue, with flexible boxes on Ipad.

I really like `-box-flex` futures in css3 but,

When I use `-webkit-box-flex: 1`  on the page, my HTML5 website is very very slow, especially I can feel it when I try to show a popup box, which already exist on the page , I just show/hide the box.

my css ex:

```
  -webkit-box-flex: 1,
   box-flex: 1
```

More flex boxes I use, slower Website gets, if I remove all flex and add static `width` and use `float`, everything works fine.

Does someone have this issue as well?  IS it a webkit bug or something else.
Does someone have a fix or an alternative way to use flex?

I found as well this info:

http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/

where they suggest to use `display: flex;` instead `display: box;` and instead

`-webkit-box-flex: 1` to use `-webkit-flex: 1`

I have tried, and really helps when I use chrome (desktop), but Ipad safari seems like doesn't support new `-webkit-flex`

I really appreciate any help or suggestion what I can do in my situation.

Thanks !!